# I can't create a new Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I try to create a controller on cakephp, but my editor does not recognize the php language.

I create a new file, ResultatsController.php but this file is not recognized as a controller.

I think the problem is the name of this file ?

```
<?php

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

// app/Controller/ResultatsController.php
class ResultatsController extends AppController
{

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }


}
```

Comment: which editor you using ? what do you mean by _recognized as a controller._ ?

Comment: What do you mean by  "but this file is not recognized as a controller". Did you get any error or something else? Exactly what do you want to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Please Use this way it very useful...

```
   <?php
 class UsersController extends AppController
  {
 var $name = 'Users'; // missing this line // please try it

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();


}
}
```